# PHPChart library - Scriptpath

Tags: javascript, php

I found a lot of questions about this topic on stackoverflow, but none fits what i encountered so far:

When i set the Scriptpath in the basic config file to:

```
define("SCRIPTPATH","inc/img/");
```

I end up with the Error:

```
WARNING: REQUIRE_ONCE(C:/XAMPP/HTDOCS/INC/IMG//CONF.PHP): FAILED TO OPEN STREAM: NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY IN
```

So i changed the Path to fit my localhost Setup, to

```
localhost/MyProjet/inc/img
```

Now i get no PHP error, but javascript errors. Either way i choose i make something wrong. What's the problem here?

JS Error Messages:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think all you have to change (removed trailing slash)

```
define("SCRIPTPATH","inc/img");
```

Comment: Nope, i tried this and tons of other variations. Didn't work!

Comment: It depends how you are including the library. Is the PHP chart library included inside "inc/img", which what I assume? define("SCRIPTPATH","PATH_TO_LIB");

Comment: Yes, of course the lib is in there. However it didn't work as i told you above.

Answer (score 0):

For everybody having something like the same problem - I sort of found an answer or at least the reason why this is happing:

phpChart seems to have a bug or at least some very weird intended behaviour. Basically it all comes down to this: When loading the php Code form phpChart, the Script takes the relative SCRIPTPATH and adds it to the localhost root, so you HAVE to adjust your SCRIPTPATH as if you were in the localhost root. However when generating javascript Code it generates it differently and uses the index.php file it is included into as the root. This results in path problems because you can't solve both criterias at once. I consider this as a bug.

This functionality was found after decoding the obfuscated phpChart Code with unphp.net. You get something like this:

```
<?php ?><?php if (str_replace('\', ' / ',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) == SCRIPTPATH) { define('_ABS_PATH_pC', '');}   else { define('_ABS_PATH_pC', SCRIPTPATH); }      require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].' / '. _ABS_PATH_pC .' / conf . php');                 class C_Config {  private $_E901A667AA80A80858A0CE75D1AB5503 = '';  protected $debug;  private $default_js = array();  private $default_css = array();  private $load_initial_js = array();  private $load_initial_css = array();  private $load_jquery_plugins = array();    public function __construct() {  }    public function set_jqplot_config(){  $this->_E901A667AA80A80858A0CE75D1AB5503 = SCRIPTPATH;  $this->debug = (defined('DEBUG'))?DEBUG:false;  $this->default_js = array('jquery . jqplot');  $this->default_css = array('jquery . jqplot');                   $this->load_initial_js = array_merge($this->default_js, explode(', ', ADDITIONAL_JS_FILES));    $this->load_initial_css = array_merge($this->default_css, explode(', ',ADDITIONAL_CSS_FILES));   }     public function get_jqplot_plugin_list(){  return $this->load_jquery_plugins;  }    public function get_scriptpath(){  return $this->_E901A667AA80A80858A0CE75D1AB5503;  }    public function get_default_js_to_load(){  return $this->default_js;  }    public function get_default_css_to_load(){  return$this->default_css;  }      }    ?>
```

You have to change this to:

```
<?php ?><?php define('_ABS_PATH_pC', SCRIPTPATH); require_once(ABS_PATH_pC . '/conf.php');                  class C_Config {  private $_E901A667AA80A80858A0CE75D1AB5503 = '';  protected $debug;  private $default_js = array();  private $default_css = array();  private $load_initial_js = array();  private $load_initial_css = array();  private $load_jquery_plugins = array();    public function __construct() {  }    public function set_jqplot_config(){  $this->_E901A667AA80A80858A0CE75D1AB5503 = SCRIPTPATH;  $this->debug = (defined('DEBUG'))?DEBUG:false;  $this->default_js = array('jquery . jqplot');  $this->default_css = array('jquery . jqplot');                   $this->load_initial_js = array_merge($this->default_js, explode(', ', ADDITIONAL_JS_FILES));    $this->load_initial_css = array_merge($this->default_css, explode(', ',ADDITIONAL_CSS_FILES));   }     public function get_jqplot_plugin_list(){  return $this->load_jquery_plugins;  }    public function get_scriptpath(){  return $this->_E901A667AA80A80858A0CE75D1AB5503;  }    pubet_default_js_to_load(){  return $this->default_js;  }    public function get_default_css_to_load(){  return$this->default_css;  }    }    ?>lic function g
```

However i strongly recommend to not use this "hack", because:

- it is illegal to decode and change phpCharts code
- i don't know if this would work in every case
- unphp.net fails at decoding the biggest .php file of the phpChart library, therefore you can't change it's content as of i don't know any other service capable of decompiling this.

My solution does work for the given scenario, however consider it as illegal and don't use it. I just posted this, because i wanted to give some insight on why it doesn't work.